# An error occurred when executing the ""cache:clear --no-warmup"" command:

Tags: php, symfony

I am learning to use symfony and php for my studies. My project requires me to update symfony to version 3.0. *. When switching from version 2.8 to 3.0. * With the composer update command, I arrive at an error in the clear cache. I have already looked on different forums but I cannot find a solution to my problem.
I give you in the rest of the post the code of the files which I think are problematic.

I have this error while updating composer:
[command prompt error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5tLK.png)
and my Kernel is :

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function __construct($environment, $debug)
    {
        date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');
        parent::__construct($environment, $debug);
    }

    public function getRootDir()
    {
        return __DIR__;
    }

    public function getCacheDir()
    {
        return \dirname(__DIR__).'/var/cache/'.$this->getEnvironment();
    }

    public function getLogDir()
    {
        return \dirname(__DIR__).'/var/logs';
    }

    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = [
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
            new Aaeima\AnnuaireBundle\AaeimaAnnuaireBundle(),
            new Aaeima\SignInBundle\AaeimaSignInBundle(),
            new Aaeima\RegisterBundle\AaeimaRegisterBundle(),
            new Aaeima\ProfileBundle\AaeimaProfileBundle(),
            new Aaeima\AdminBundle\AaeimaAdminBundle(),
        ];

        if (\in_array($this->getEnvironment(), ['dev', 'test'])) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader): void
    {
        $loader->load($this->getRootDir().'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
        /*$loader->load(__DIR__.'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');*/
    }
}
```

And my .json is :

```
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
          "": "src/"
        },
    "classmap": [ "app/AppKernel.php", "app/AppCache.php" ]
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.9",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.0.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "twitter/bootstrap": "*",
        "components/jquery": "1.9.*@dev",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "dev-master",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^5.0",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^2.3",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
      "sensio/generator-bundle":"^3.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
          "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
          "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
          "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
          "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
          "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
          "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
          "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
          "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
          "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
          "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
          "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
          "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin",
        "component-dir": "web/components",
        "component-baseurl": "/components"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-var-dir": "var",
        "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        }
    },
    "repositories": [
    {
       "type": "package",
       "package": {
           "version": "3",
           "name": "twitter/bootstrap",
           "source": {
               "url": "https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap.git",
               "type": "git",
               "reference": "master"
           },
           "dist": {
               "url": "https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/zipball/master",
               "type": "zip"
           }
        }
    }]

}
```

I have already delete the vendor and run an update but nothing change. I think my composer json is valid.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the output and the composer file, it seems you need to require the Doctrine/DoctrineBundle package. https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle

Including that in the composer.json file and run a `composer update` should fix it.